# Add Arguments to Existing PHP Function from Array

Tags: php, arrays, function, arguments

I'm looking to figure out how to add more arguments to a function call based on an Array and can't figure out what I need to do.  The function in question doesn't work with simply passing an array, but the array has to explode somehow as if each array element was a new argument in the function call.    I don't think call_user_func_array works but perhaps I don't know how to execute it properly.  To give some context, the array of arguments are coming from a varying amount of $_GET arguments which is processed by an API class file I have no control over, but it appears that I can add a lot of arguments that allow the results to filter.

```
$arrayofarguments = array("dynamicarg1","dynamicarg2","dynamicarg3");

$runthis = example($staticargument1,
                 $staticargument2,
                 $staticargument3,
                 $arrayofarguments,
                 $staticargument4); 

//run the results
echo $runthis;
```

Expected result

```
$runthis = example($staticargument1,
                 $staticargument2,
                 $staticargument3,
                 "dynamicarg1",
                 "dynamicarg2",
                 "dynamicarg3",
                 $staticargument4);
```

Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to do something like

```
function example("blaa","foo","bar",$arrayofarguments,"test") {

  $args = func_get_args();

  // $arg[3] would be $arrayofarguments
  foreach ( $arg[3] as $function) {
    $function(); // this calls the function
  }
}
```

Comment: It does meet OPs requirements (provided it works) :/

Comment: I would like to point out that it's **very dangerous** to accept and run arbitrary function names from GET. If you can't change this, at the very least you should implement a whitelist of allowed functions.

Comment: Thanks! I realized now I should have qualified this a bit more.  What would I do in the event I don't have the ability to access the actual function?  I will edit my ask in light of this.   So the case would be no function but calling example() function but not being able to edit it.

Comment: @Dyluck `if (function_exists($function)) { $fuction(); }` will call the function only if it exists.